# 3.5" FDD to SATA / USB

Tags: hard-drive, usb, motherboard, sata, floppy

Motherboards these days don't tend to have floppy cable/bus pins. It's a bit "old hat" I suppose.

I have such a motherboard, but would like to connect an internal floppy drive to it. It's the sort of drive that's usualy sold as a 7 in 1 floppy and media card drive.

It has a USB connector, but also the old fashioned floppy bus connector and a power connector.

I would like to know if such an adapter exists that I can convert the floppy bus connector, either to a SATA port, or to an internal USB pinout?

Comment: 3.5 inch or 5 1/4 inch? And yes, most modern PCs don't come with floppy drive interfaces, or bays for that matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a floppy drive controller (you can't simple convert a floppy cable to USB), but they basically just don't exist anymore.

You'll probably just have to get a USB floppy drive and a USB card reader, and live with two separate devices.